# What's the most effective way to boost frame rate in Quake 3 and derivates?

Tags: quake-3, id-tech-3

What set of options and console commands help the most in improving frames per seconds in [id Tech 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id_Tech_3) games (that is, Quake 3 and [derivates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id_Tech_3#Uses_of_the_engine))?

Comment: Do you care whether or not you lose massive amounts of quality? You could reduce texture sizes and resolution.

Comment: That would be an acceptable answer @McKay.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with the quake console, so I would be unable to provide specific answers. But you can go into the video options, and change those things manually.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an autoexec.cfg generator](http://www.quaketweaks.com/config.html) that explains what some of the options do as well.

[Here is also another site](http://www.planetquake3.net/tweak/glossary_commands.html) that lists the configs and explains them.

The main console command is `r_picmip`, this will increase FPS most overall. [Here is an example of picmip 5](http://bsan.up.seesaa.net/image/picmip_03.jpg)

Comment: Is it a glitch in Chrome or the letter spacing in that website is horribly large?

Comment: It is horrible in firefox as well.

Answer (score 1):

r_picmip is your best bet. It reduces all textures to flat, base colors. This is how competitive Quake is played, along with "cg_forcemodel Keel". Since Keel is a bright green, he sticks out the most against these base textures. The forcemodel is completely optional, but picmip will help you achieve 125fps.